# How can I use Dropbox API to access files hosted on my own computer?

Tags: ios, streaming, dropbox-api

I have a question about the Dropbox API. I may or may not be going about this the right way, but I would like to develop a simple app for iOS that allows me to use the clean Dropbox interface to access files on my computer, **not ones hosted on Dropbox servers.** I'd like to be able to stream music from my computer straight to my device, without worrying about storing the files in the Dropbox cloud. (I have about 120 GB of music) Is the Dropbox API the right approach? How should I get started? Thanks for any advice - I don't expect a complete solution, just ideas so I can get started on the work myself.

Thank you!

Comment: No, the Dropbox API would not be the right choice for this.

Comment: OK, am I looking at something I should do with an FTP platform?

Comment: Would the iOS API be good for this? How should I start?